# wp_nav_menu() in Wordpress 3.6 ignores parameters or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have this code in my templates:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '' ) ); ?>
```

It outputs the menu but wrapped in `<div class="menu">`
As I understand [the documentation page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) it should not output the .

Comment: Which version of WP are you using? Try using `false` instead of `''`. As the documentation says, _Use false for no container e.g. `'container' => false`_.

Comment: Theoretically, PHP understands `''` or `0` as `false` in some situations, depending on the condition/comparison check that is made. I prefer to use Boolean `false` when I mean ___false___ and always use [Identical Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in my codes (whenever possible) to avoid these kind of mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got it. You need to set: `menu' => 'Name of the menu'`
and `'theme_location'=> 'main_menu'` as well... something like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu' => 'Name of the menu',    
'container_class' => 'main-menu2', 'container_id' => 'menu-l', 'theme_location'  => 'main- 
 menu') ); ?>
```

Maybe someone could use this as well :)